# Anyone knows how to set a custom action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Anyone knows how to set a green action bar with the logo of my app and the name of the app, i've tried it but it appears white  with no logo.

My MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity. Thats why I need to use Theme.AppCompat in  Manifest.xml

Here's style.XML

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>">

</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorVerd</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlanc</item>
</style>
```

My android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>


        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
<receiver android:name=".Alarm_Receiver1"/>
<receiver android:name=".Alarm_Receiver2"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity is an `AppCompatActivity` so you should use an appcompat theme as well,To change your toolbar attributes override `toolbarStyle`, Modify the `styles.xml` file like this:

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorVerd</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/Blanc</item>
</style>
```

**Update**

In order to show your desired  logo use these lines of code in `onCreate` method:

```
    toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
    toolbar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
```

Comment: Wow thanks! The logo is still not there though:( Do you know how to put it? @NaN

Comment: My pleasure, It's a little off topic but I update my answer, check it.

Comment: Thanks NaN I aprecciate it ;)))